# MongoDB - Update a field based on another field within the same doc in the array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization, mongodb-update

I have a collection of data like this:

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "product": {
          "name": "prod1",
          "price": {
            "pledge": 1,
            "cost": 19
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "product": {
          "name": "prod2",
          "price": {
            "pledge": 2,
            "cost": 10
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to update the whole collection have them like this:

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "product": {
          "name": "prod1",
          "price": {
            "pledge": 1,
            "deposit": 1,
            "cost": 19
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "product": {
          "name": "prod2",
          "price": {
            "pledge": 2,
            "deposit": 2,
            "cost": 10
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

For each `price` in the `items`, I want to add a new field named `deposit` with the value of `pledge` in the same element.
How can I do it in an optimized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should need the [update query with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to reference the field.

1. `$map` - Iterate the elements in the `items` array

1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterated object with the document with `price` field.

1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the `product.price` object with the document with `deposit` field referencing the `product.price.pledge` value.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {
            product: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$this.product",
                {
                  "price": {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this.product.price",
                      {
                        deposit: "$$this.product.price.pledge"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zo1270gUwZS)

Comment: thank you very much, If I want to add a condition there to add the deposit if pledge is less than 100, what should I add in the query?

Comment: Should be as this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h8XsSCpQl0Q) with `$cond` operator.

Comment: there is another problem I have with it, if we have any other key near the product, this script remove those keys and only product key remains

Comment: In that case, you need the `$mergeObjects` same as what I did in the question. `$mergeObjects: ["$$this", { product: { ... } }]`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of updateMany() for this.

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
  {}, // Match all documents
  {
    $set: {
      "items.$[elem].product.price.deposit": "$items.$[elem].product.price.pledge"
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{"elem.product.price.pledge": {$exists: true}}], // Filter to match all documents that have the pledge field
    multi: true // Apply to all documents
  }
)
```

- `updateMany` targets all documents in the collection ({} as the first
  argument).
- The `$set` operator is used to assign the deposit field a value equal
  to the pledge field within each price object of each item in the
  items array.
- `arrayFilters` specifies the conditions for the elements that the
  update should apply to. Here, it ensures the operation only applies
  to elements where the pledge exists.
- The `multi: true` option, although redundant in updateMany, emphasizes
  the intention to update multiple documents. It's more relevant in
  update operations.

NOTE: Replace collectionName with the right name of your collection.

Edit: Making use of map and merge:

```
db.collection.update({},
// Match all documents
[
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$item",
              {
                product: {
                  $mergeObjects: [
                    "$$item.product",
                    {
                      price: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$item.product.price",
                          {
                            deposit: "$$item.product.price.pledge"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: it doesn't help, because instead of the value`$items.$[elem].product.price.pledge` it'd be the string '$items.$[elem].product.price.pledge'.

Comment: Ah true. Have made an edit. That should work.

Comment: @Niusoski, the basic update query cannot get the reference field value with `$`. Please check your answer before posting. Thanks.